# How do I ignore certain sets from a given array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays

Here's the problem I have, I'm trying to separate News by categories, I have the following txt file (which includes all of the news divided by

```
 <item></item>
```

Here is a set of 4 News, on my actual file I have thousands.

```
 <item>
 Title: News from Washington
 Author: John Doe
 Category: New Laws
 Body: News content...
 </item>

 <item>
 Title: News from Texas
 Author: General Lee
 Category: Road Accidents
 Body: News content/
 </item>

 <item>
 Title: News from Georgia
 Author: Marcus Smith
 Category: Street Food
 Body: News content
 </item>

 <item>
 Title: News from Illinois
 Author: Robert Simpson
 Category: School Projects
 Body: News content
 </item>
```

I have the following coding:

```
//I get the content from the news file:
 $news = file_get_contents("news.txt");

//Then I create the following variables to get each set of news from the news variable:
 $regexp = '@<item>(.*?)</item>@msi';
```

what I want to do from here is that in case that I just want to get a file with News which includes just the "Street Food" as a category and to dismiss/ignore the rest of the other News with different categories.

e.g.

My result from the above example will be a file which only includes this item:

```
 <item>
 Title: News from Georgia
 Author: Marcus Smith
 Category: Street Food
 Body: News content
 </item>
```

I tried using a preg_match_all and a foreach function to get a set of news with certain category with no luck.

What do you suggest to accomplish this? or if you could provide me with an example that'll be great.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this actual XML? Are you pulling this from some external source you can't control, or are you actually storing this in a file yourself? If it's the former, why aren't you using a database?

Comment: Indeed it is an XML file, that can be used as an importer and I do get it from an external source I can't control.

Comment: These people are sloppy. If they are already using XML, why not properly structure the data? (eg: `<item> <title>News from Georgia</title> <author>Marcus Smith</author> ... </item>`)

Comment: it's from an old Movable Type version.

Comment: Now, repeat after me. XML cannot be parsed using regular expressions. XML cannot be parsed using regular expressions. XML cannot be parsed using regular expressions...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
$final = array();
$filename = "log.txt";
$news = simplexml_load_file($filename);

foreach ( $news as $item ) {
    $item = trim($item);
    $content = array();
    foreach ( explode("\n", $item) as $info ) {
        list($title, $data) = explode(":", $info);
        $content[trim($title)] = $data;
    }
    $final[trim($content['Category'])][] = $content;
}


#Remove Street Food
unset($final['Street Food']);

#Output The Rest 
var_dump($final);
```

Output

```
    array
  'New Laws' => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          'Title' => string ' News from Washington' (length=21)
          'Author' => string ' John Doe' (length=9)
          'Category' => string ' New Laws' (length=9)
          'Body' => string ' News content...' (length=16)
  'Road Accidents' => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          'Title' => string ' News from Texas' (length=16)
          'Author' => string ' General Lee' (length=12)
          'Category' => string ' Road Accidents' (length=15)
          'Body' => string ' News content/' (length=14)
  'School Projects' => 
    array
      0 => 
        array
          'Title' => string ' News from Illinois' (length=19)
          'Author' => string ' Robert Simpson' (length=15)
          'Category' => string ' School Projects' (length=16)
          'Body' => string ' News content' (length=13)
```

You can also `Rewrite The XML` using the following

```
#Rewrite the array to new XML Fromat
rewriteToXML($final,"log.xml");
```

This would return

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<items>
    <item>
        <Title> News from Washington</Title>
        <Author> John Doe</Author>
        <Category> New Laws</Category>
        <Body> News content...</Body>
    </item>
    <item>
        <Title> News from Texas</Title>
        <Author> General Lee</Author>
        <Category> Road Accidents</Category>
        <Body> News content/</Body>
    </item>
    <item>
        <Title> News from Illinois</Title>
        <Author> Robert Simpson</Author>
        <Category> School Projects</Category>
        <Body> News content</Body>
    </item>
</items>
```

Reading new format easier

```
$final = array();
$filename = "log.xml";
$news = simplexml_load_file($filename);

foreach ( $news as $item ) {
    #Check if not Street Food
    if(trim($item->Category) != 'Street Food')
            $final[trim($item->Category)][] = (array) $item;
}

#Output The Rest
var_dump($final);
```

Re Write Function

```
function rewriteToXML($array, $fileName = null) {
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement("<items />");
    foreach ( $array as $key => $item ) {
        $child = $xml->addChild("item");
        foreach ( $item as $list ) {
            foreach ( $list as $title => $data ) 
            {
                $child->addChild($title, $data);
            }
        }
    }
    $xml->asXML($fileName);
}
```

Comment: Cool Baba! The second option seems perfect, as @Joshua mentioned simpleXML was the best way to achieve this, I'll try it and see if it works!, brb :)

Comment: Wrote the function to Items would be SimpleXMLElement even if you use `simplexml_load_file` .... you can use  `rewriteToXML` the do convert from one your current format to the other ...

Answer (score 0):

If this is an xml file, I would use simpleXML instead of a regex.  Then you can query the simpleXML document using xQuery.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

Comment: Not really sure why this got marked down.  You can load the example given above into a simpleXML dom document and then generate an xPath to find what you are looking for.